# Incomplete inner product spaces can be completed to Hilbert spaces

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis

I have a hard time understanding the following theorem quoted from Conway's *A Course in Functional Analysis*.

> **1.9. Proposition.** If $\mathscr{X}$ is a vector space and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_\mathscr{X}$ is an inner product on $\mathscr{X}$ and if $\mathscr{H}$ is the completion of $\mathscr{X}$ with respect to the metric induced by the norm on $\mathscr{X}$, then there is an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_\mathscr{H}$ on $\mathscr{H}$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle_\mathscr{H}=\langle x,y\rangle_\mathscr{X}$ for $x$ and $y$ in $\mathscr{X}$ and the metric on $\mathscr{H}$ is induced by this inner product. That is, the completion of $\mathscr{X}$ is a Hilbert space.

With the help of the norm on $\mathscr{X}$, we can turn $\mathscr{X}$ into a metric space, for which, according to Munkres' *Topology*, there is an isometric embedding $h$ of $\mathscr{X}$ in a complete metric space $(Y,D)$. Then the closure of $h(\mathscr{X})$ is a complete metric space in the relative metric induced by the metric $D$, called the comletion of $\mathscr{X}$. Following Conway's notation, we denote this completion by the symbol $\mathscr{H}$. Now I have three questions for you:

1. If $\mathscr{H}$ is to be an inner product space, it must be a vector space at first. Is it really a vector space? How?
2. The equation $\langle x,y\rangle_\mathscr{H}=\langle x,y\rangle_\mathscr{X}$ seems like an abuse of notation. How can one feed the inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_\mathscr{H}$ with vectors in $\mathscr{X}$? Is $\langle h(x),h(y)\rangle_\mathscr{H}=\langle x,y\rangle_\mathscr{X}$ what Conway really means?
3. Finally, **is** the metric induced by $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_\mathscr{H}$ on $\mathscr{H}$, based on what I know about the theorem, **equal to** the relative metric induced by $D$ on $\mathscr{H}$?

Thank you.

Comment: You can probably work out the answers to your questions from the special case $\mathscr{X}=\Bbb Q^n,\,\mathscr{H}=\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: To add on to what @J.G. hinted, see exercise 9 in Munkres' section 43 on Complete Metric Spaces. If $X$ is an incomplete metric space, what are the elements in the Cauchy completion $\overline{X}$? If you could add and scale things in $X$, could you do the same in $\overline{X}$?

The answer to your second question is, yes. By the _isometric embedding_ you can think of $X$ as a subspace of $H$, so the abuse of notation makes sense. The answer t you third question is also yes. Again this follows by defining the inner product on the $H$ using Cauchy sequences and using continuity.

Answer (score 2):

Everything can be solved by the following theorem: if $A\subset X$ is a dense subset, $Y$ is complete and $f\colon A\to Y$ is uniformly continuous (at least locally, i.e. on bounded subsets) then there exists only one extension $F\colon X\to Y$ of $f$.

One can use it for the addition, multiplication by a scalar, and for the inner product.

Yes, it is the abuse of notation, based on the identification $x\equiv h(x)$.